# Number of ways to distribute 4 objects in 6 drawers with some restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The question is: We have 4 different objects, and 6 drawers on top of another. So the question in how many ways can we distribute the objects to the drawers so that the top drawer will have **exactly** one object, and the bottom drawer will have **at least**  one object.

The way that I solved it:

We have to put exactly one object to the top drawer. We have 4 objects so we have 4 options. So let's assume we put one of them in the top drawer. And we want to put at least 1 object to the bottom drawer, we have 3 objects which means we have three options of putting them (Because we have 3 objects left, and we want to put one so there can be at least one). Lets assume that we put one of them. so we have 2 objects that we can put wherever we  want but not in the first drawer so, we have 5 options for each(all drawers besides the top drawer). So my answer was $4.3.5.5=300$ but according to the solution  the answer is 244, and I understood their explanation. However I do not understand my counting is wrong? I would really appreciate if someone can give me an explanation to why my counting was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overcounted. Suppose that in one distribution you give object $1$ to the bottom drawer, and object $2$ to the first drawer, and then start distributing the rest of the objects. Let's say you put object $3$ in the bottom drawer as well (and nothing else), and object $4$ in second drawer say.

Now consider another arrangement:

you give object $3$ to the bottom drawer, and object $2$ to the first drawer, and then start distributing the rest of the objects. Let's say you put object $1$ in the bottom drawer as well (and nothing else), and object $4$ in second drawer.

Notice that finally both these distributions are identical, but you have counted them as separate in your argument.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you for the explanation it really helped!

Comment: @CharlesCarmichael: Glad to help :). Do I get an upvote ;-) (jk- glad to help anyway).

Comment: I am pretty new to this site, it's kind of complicated, how do you give an upvote? I would be more than happy to give haha

Comment: @CharlesCarmichael: Notice the arrow pointing upwards- you just need to click that :).

Comment: Great! I did it, thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

You count the cases where you put more than one into the bottom drawer multiple times.
With your idea made correctly you need
$$\{1 \text{ in bottom}\} + \{2 \text{ in bottom}\} + \{3 \text{ in bottom}\} = 4\cdot3\cdot4\cdot4 + 4\cdot \binom32 \cdot 4 + 4 = 244$$
Wich is formulated as
$$\sum_{k=1}^3 4_{\text{top}} \cdot \binom3k_{\text{bottom}} \cdot 4^{3-k}_{\text{other}}$$